# downloading data from UNdata onto ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, data, convert, download

http://data.un.org/Search.aspx?q=population

I am trying to download data from UNdata and successfully opened one link of raster data, however the data that I really desire won't open on Arc. I hit the download button and it gives me the choices of XML, Comma, Semicolon, and Pipe. I can download the XML to a zipfile to the correct folder and drag it onto the Arc page but then it simply says "could not open specified file". It doesn't like the XML file. This data would be perfect for my project, is there any way I could get it to show up? or is it simply not compatible?

Comment: Which dataset in particular are you trying to download? I tried the population density layer, and its all tabular - nothing to 'map' that I can see...unless you had a 'countries' layer that you could join to on the 'name' field. In that case, try using the 'comma' download option and see what you can do ... it should go into Arc/QGIS nicely.

Comment: Well I would like to use multiple, but to start: Total population, both sexes combined (thousands). Thanks for the idea of joining the names!

Comment: yeah I think that's all you can do with that data, is to join it to a countries layer and hope all the names match in both tables! Can be a headache when joining on Text, so watch out! Maybe Natural Earth data can be a good place to start: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/ (click the "countries" download)

Comment: @mapBaker please put your comments as an answer

Answer (score 1):

With that data, download the 'comma' version. Then load it as a table/tab delimted file into QGIS or ArcMap.

Then you'll need to join it to a countries layer (and hope all the names match in both tables! This can be a headache when joining on Text, so watch out!)

A good place to start for Country data to join to can be found via Natural Earth: naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors (click the "countries" download)